# tmux detach session remote

Tags: terminal, tmux

I run at first terminal tmux, then I run another terminal with tmux and attach to session which I run at first terminal. First is smaller than second and I can't go to it to do something.

How to detach session from first and attach at second terminal using only that second one?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.dayid.org/comp/tm.html

re-attach an attached session (detaching it from elsewhere)

```
tmux attach -d
```

OR

```
tmux attach-session -d
```